# Accessing checkbox inside a html table loop, from code behind (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html, checkbox

Hey guys,
I have a question about asp.net

I have this table with checkbox for each row:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QBLf.png

table code inside the ASPX page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLbP1.png

So I'm trying to implement the delete selected button.. 
How exactly do i point to the specific checkbox for a particular row from codebehind when all 3 have the same name chkSelected?
I know how to do it with a gridview, but not quite sure how if we do it with a for loop..

Can I do something like this inside btnDelete_Click?

```
    foreach (Control control in Controls)
    {
        try
        {
            CheckBox chkCurrent = (CheckBox)control;
            if (chkCurrent.Checked)
            {
                Partners partner = new Partners(chkCurrent.ID); <- reference id here
                partner.Delete();
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could add a HTML Hidden Field and set its value to the ID you are looking for. But IMHO you should give up on ASP classic approach and code .Net style (at least code behind without mixing visible and data layers).

Comment: You're right. I guess I thought its cleaner this way since its a very simple page. But turned out it makes my life harder because i still need to manually code pagination as well... Hmm.. So if I were to rewrite this page, whats the best way to go? Gridview, DataList, Repeater or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebForms ASP.Net is kinda old and busted, but I would suggest just doing it brute-force and forgoing ASP.Net's control layer. Render each checkbox with a unique name thusly:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="select_press<%= i %>" ...
```

Then, in your codebehind, inspect the Request collection for the presence of each checkbox.

Comment: dirty but it works like a charm without breaking a sweat. didnt know we could do that. thanks!